# Google Sheets Concatenate an Array of IFs

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation

My goal is to create an Array of IF statements, all independent of each other, and concatenate them together into one cell. I'm currently using an expanded version of this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(D2=1,$D$1,""),IF(E2=1,$E$1,""),IF(F2=1,$F$1,""))
```

I've only posted a few cells, as the current formula goes to column "O" instead of ending at "F". The new spreadsheet I'm working on will go to past CA, and I'd really like to not have to type all the cells out individually.

Is there a way I can repeat this IF statement in an ARRAY so that I can specify the start and end, instead of typing out every IF statement per column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Sheets has JOIN and Filter

Join will concatenate and filter will filter on the 1

```
=join(",",filter($D$1:$F$1,D2:F2 = 1))
```

You can change the `","` to `""` if you do not want a deliminator.  Or just replace join with concatenate:

```
=CONCATENATE(FILTER($D$1:$F$1,D2:F2 = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hot diggity dog. I couldn't get that JOIN function to work when I tried, but now I see the syntax I used was wrong. Thank you for this!